# how to redirect to another component in vue 3 using AXIOS after getting API response inside ( then block )

Tags: javascript, http, axios, http-status-code-200

I am trying to implement some code based on HTTP status code in success response using AXIOS call , How can i access the status code of HTTP response header , and redirect to ano[image]ther component  in vu3

Comment: Please post formatted text instead of pictures of formatted text. There’s no need to parse what is already a number. Note that the docs are your friend; this is in the Axios docs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is something like. `const response = await axios.post("<url>");` You can check with `if (response.status === 200)`. Read the full response schema [here.](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `response.status` to tap into the status code

> response.status

```
    app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
        //your code
        console.log(response.status);//this will console the status of the request
    });
```

Comment: It is working , i was not access directly , thank you